# OrderBy used with LINQ returns no rows in DOcumentDb

Tags: linq, sql-order-by, azure-cosmosdb

I have been trying to use OrderBy in LINQ i have changed several fields but it always returns null (no rows) while my documents are present in the collection.
Here's my simple query-

```
        var rests = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Restraunt>(_collectionUri)
                         .OrderBy(x => x.RestName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an indexing policy with a range index on the type of the property you use in the order by (here I assume a string).

If you let the default policy, the order by return no result.

You need a sorting policy like that :

```
restrauntsCollection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(
    new IncludedPath { 
        Path = "/RestName/?", 
        Indexes = new Collection<Index> { 
            new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 } } 
        });
```

See this page for more information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-orderby/

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for help, i added the above code , now it works on all the integers but still not on string . It returns the documents for numbers but when i try string field it returns nothing .

Comment: ok, maybe you have to adapt the code and not just to use it as in (as I don't know your project), but I really think your solution is to configure indexing policy correctly :)

Comment: Thanks for help @Julien is there any way to check the current indexing policy being implemented by default? i mean like i can view in console which paths are included which are not?

Comment: You're welcome ! Happy to help :) I don't think that there is a specific tool to check your indexing policy but I think you can use the .NET SDK to browse the policies as you use it to configure it.